# Percentages with Arrays

Tags: python

Hi i've been having trouble with this python program. it keeps saying the percentage is = to 0.0

```
players_goals = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
players_fouls = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]

players_goals[0] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 1 then press enter "))
players_goals[1] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 2 then press enter "))
players_goals[2] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 3 then press enter "))
players_goals[3] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 4 then press enter "))
players_goals[4] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 5 then press enter "))
players_goals[5] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 6 then press enter "))
players_goals[6] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 7 then press enter "))
players_goals[7] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 8 then press enter "))
players_goals[8] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 9 then press enter "))
players_goals[9] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 10 then press enter "))
players_goals[10] = int(input("type in number of goals for player 11 then press enter "))

players_fouls[0] = int(input("Now type in number of fouls for player 1 then press enter "))
players_fouls[1] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 2 then press enter "))
players_fouls[2] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 3 then press enter "))
players_fouls[3] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 4 then press enter "))
players_fouls[4] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 5 then press enter "))
players_fouls[5] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 6 then press enter "))
players_fouls[6] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 7 then press enter "))
players_fouls[7] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 8 then press enter "))
players_fouls[8] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 9 then press enter "))
players_fouls[9] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 10 then press enter "))
players_fouls[10] = int(input("type in number of fouls for player 11 then press enter "))

print""                       
print"the total number of goals is ", players_goals[0] + players_goals[1] + players_goals[2] + players_goals[3] + players_goals[4] + players_goals[5] + players_goals[6] + players_goals[7] + players_goals[8] + players_goals[9] + players_goals[10]
print"the total number of fouls is ", players_fouls[0] + players_fouls[1] + players_fouls[2] + players_fouls[3] + players_fouls[4] + players_fouls[5] + players_fouls[6] + players_fouls[7] + players_fouls[8] + players_fouls[9] + players_fouls[10]

print"player 1's goal percentage is ", (players_goals[0] / (players_fouls[0] + players_goals[0])) * 100.0
```

my problem is in the last line. no matter what i put in it will always = 0

Thanks for the help
p.s. i'm using python 3.4.1

Comment: My God, Jim, have you never heard of loops? :-)

Comment: Are you dividing `int`s? `(49/50) * 100.0)` is `0.0`. `(49.0/50) * 100.0` is `98.0`

Comment: @MohitJain: Not on Python 3 (and the OP claims he's using 3.4.1). `49/50` is `0.98`, not `0`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks. I was not sure, that's why I put my speculation in comment.

Comment: On the other hand… if this is Python 3.4.1, those `print` statements are going to raise `SyntaxError`s, so… maybe that's the problem. He thinks he's using 3.x, but he's actually running his code under 2.x?

Comment: seems a python 2.x problem. Check your python version by type `python --version`

Answer (score -1):

If you input the positive integer number, players_goals[0] <= (players_fouls[0] + players_goals[0].
So players_goals[0] / (players_fouls[0] + players_goals[0] = 0, like 2/(1+2) = 0 in python.
You can use float instead of integer.